# Usar um tabbed panel dentro de outro

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando utilizar um tabbed panel dentro de outro.
O problema que estou enfrentando é:
-A partir da segunda aba que eu seleciono ele insere a opção e não substitui
Exemplo com imagens abaixo:

Primeira seleção-OK
[image: Primeira seleção-OK]

[image: A partir da segunda seleção ele adiciona a opção inves de substituir]

A partir da segunda seleção ele adiciona a opção inves de substituir.

Código para implementação dos tabs(simplificado):

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
  <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-669585">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li>
      <a href=" #panel-21 " data-toggle="tab">Maio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href=" #panel-22 " data-toggle="tab">Junho</a>
  </li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">Atividade</div>
  <div class="panel-body">  
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-21">
        ...(código das abas)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-22">
        ...(código das abas)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OBS: Cortei o código das abas para não ficar muito extenso

Comment: Cadê os `<li>` da sua `<ul>`?

Comment: Está no código,esqueci de copiar,vou editar.